# Proving the difference quotient has a removable discontinuity

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I need some help on showing how the function $g(h)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ has a removable discontinuity at $h = 0 \Longleftrightarrow f'(a)$ exists. I understand that for a function to have a removable discontinuity :

$1)$ $g(0)$ is not defined, which is clear from the equation and,

$2)$ Both $\lim_{h\to0^+}$ and $\lim_{h\to0^-}$ are the same.

But for $2)$, since these are general functions, what is a method for showing the latter?

Comment: It is an if and only if statement. So if you assume $f'(a)$ exists, then by the limit definition of the derivative $\lim_{h \to 0}g(h)$ exists, which means both side limits $\lim_{h \to 0^+}g(h)$ and $\lim_{h \to 0^-}g(h)$ exist. Similarly if we assume that $g$ has a removable discontinuity, then by the definition, $\lim_{h \to 0}g(h)$ exists (is finite), so $f'(a)$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is true by definition and there is (almost) nothing to prove:

> $f'(a)$ exists if and only if $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h$ exists;

> $\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h$ has a removable discontinuity at $h=0$ if and only if $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h$ exists.